# Grouping query while providing extra selects

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql, derby

I have the following query

```
select t1.file_name, 
       max(create_date), 
       t1.id 
 from dbo.translation_style_sheet AS t1 
GROUP BY t1.file_name
```

I'd like to add the id to the select, but everytime I do this, it returns all results rather than my grouped results

my goal is to return

```
pdf | 10/1/2012 | 3
doc | 10/2/2012 | 5
```

however my query is returning

```
pdf | 9/30/2012 | 1
pdf | 9/31/2012 | 2
pdf | 10/1/2012 | 3
doc | 10/1/2012 | 4
doc | 10/2/2012 | 5
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You've tagged this for a number of different databases.  Do you want a query that works with any of them?  All of them?  Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are guaranteed that the row with the `max(create_date)` also has the largest `id` value (your sample data does but I don't know if that is an artifact), you can simply select the `max(id)`

```
select t1.file_name, max(create_date), max(t1.id) 
  from dbo.translation_style_sheet AS t1 
 GROUP BY t1.file_name
```

If you are not guaranteed that, and you want the `id` value that is from the row that has the `max(create_date)` to be returned, you can use analytic functions.  The following will work in Oracle though it is unlikely that less sophisticated databases like Derby would support it.

```
select t1.file_name, t1.create_date, t1.id
  from (select t2.file_name,
               t2.create_date,
               t2.id,
               rank() over (partition by t2.file_name 
                                order by t2.create_date desc) rnk
          from dbo.translation_style_sheet t2) t1 
  where rnk = 1
```

You could also use a subquery.  This is likely to be more portable but less efficient than the analytic function approach

```
select t1.file_name, t1.create_date, t1.id
  from dbo.translation_style_sheet t1
 where (t1.file_name, t1.create_date) in (select t2.file_name, max(t2.create_date)
                                            from dbo.translation_style_sheet t2
                                           group by t2.file_name);
```

or

```
select t1.file_name, t1.create_date, t1.id
  from dbo.translation_style_sheet t1
 where t1.create_date = (select max(t2.create_date) 
                           from dbo.translation_style_sheet t2
                          where t1.file_name = t2.file_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using GROUP BY, you have to include all fields in the group that aren't being used by the aggregate function.

```
select t1.file_name, max(create_date), t1.id from 
dbo.translation_style_sheet AS t1 GROUP BY t1.file_name, t1.id
```